# How can I use a Global Mixin method from a Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-mixin

Let's suppose that I have the following situation, using a Global Mixin to create a global helper method with Vue:

```
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        replaceString: function (word) {
            return word.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, '');
        }
    }
});

let vm = new Vue({
    methods: {
        doSomething: function() {
             console.log(this.replaceString('Hello World'); //helloword
        }
    }
});
```

I know that I can invoke the method inside the other methods, inside of the component and their childs. But how can I invoke the mixin method "replaceString" from the Vue instance "vm"?
I tried to use "vm.replaceString", but keeps returning "undefined".

Comment: It says at docs that you can transform it into a component, so you would just import it and use. Take a look at the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Answer (score 2):

Few changes to your code and it works:

1. You should change the definition of your mixin (var mixin instead of Vue.mixin)
2. Import the mixin to your new vue component (mixins = [mixin])

   ```
   import Vue from "vue";

   var mixin = {
       methods: {
           replaceString: function (word) {
               return word.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, '');
           }
       }
   };

   let vm = new Vue({
       mixins: [mixin]
       methods: {
           doSomething: function() {
               console.log(this.replaceString('Hello World'); //helloword
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think this chunk o code is what you are looking for:

```
var mixin = {
methods: {
foo: function () {
  console.log('foo')
},
   conflicting: function () {
      console.log('from mixin')
   }
 }
}

var vm = new Vue({
  mixins: [mixin],
methods: {
  bar: function () {
  console.log('bar')
  },
    conflicting: function () {
      console.log('from self')
    }
  }
})

vm.foo() // => "foo"
vm.bar() // => "bar"
vm.conflicting() // => "from self"
```

From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)